# QAudioDecoder seeking in file

Tags: qt, audio

I want to develop a QT5.7 based music player. The player must have the following features:

- Format support for MP3,WAV,MIDI
- Change the playback speed with pitch correction
- Loop function (repeat part of a file)

With my current approach, the first and the second part works fine.
I use QAudioDecoder --> Soundtouch Library --> QAudioOutput.
By implementing the last feature I have realized that there is no function in QAudioDecoder to change the play position.

How can I do this?